# Get autocompletion with PyCharm on widgets created with qtdesigner

Tags: python, qt, intellij-idea, pycharm, pyqt5

**Context**

I code with pyqt5 and python. Recently, I couldn't get autocompletion working for the objects inside the imported .ui > .py files from qtdesigner. I'd like to know how to get that autocompletion back on PyCharm 2019.

**Code**

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


someWidgetPath= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\someWidgetUi.ui'
Ui_someWidget, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(someWidgetPath)


class SomeNewWidget(QWidget, Ui_someWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphManagerWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi()
        self.XXX
```

There is no autocompletion on this XXX. In my .ui, I have a textEdit named te_name, but it doesn't appear. Thus, I always have to go back to my qtdesigner, lookup the name I gave the QObjects and then write it in the code. Sometimes, I find this time consuming.

**Setup**

```
Windows==10.0.1
Python==3.7.6
PyQt5==5.14.1
QtDesigner==5.11.1
PyCharm==2019.3.3
```

Comment: Have you tried installing pyqt5-stubs package?
https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-stubs/

Comment: What is this package doing, it is unclear in the doc? I mean, it is the compiled version, to allow for type checking. But it doesn't seem to grant what I wish (I installed it)

Comment: Briefly speaking, stubs can help PyCharm with autocompletion. But, I have doubts that PyCharm can provide completion for elements inside your .ui file. I may be wrong, never worked with it. Could you provide a minimal working example to reproduce the issue?